# Get Alexa to send the current Spotify song to a list

Tags: if-this-then-that, spotify, alexa-skill

I am thinking about a way to make Alexa send the currently playing song to a list, so whenever I discover a new music I really like I can say "Alexa, get me this song" and she sends this one specific song to my Spotify list. IFTTT offers tools to send Spotify music to lists but not the specific one playing at the time.

My first strategy was:

1- Alexa, what is playing? # and then she answers
2- Alexa, add *name of the music* (which she just told me) to my to do list
3- Set IFTTT to get a Spotify music to a list when I add a to do
4- Set the "then" Spotify part to use the string in the to-do to search the music

But there are two problems:
a) Spotify searches with the string you give it and adds the first result, which may or may not be what you wanted.
b) Spotify would add something when you add a to do, even if it's not music, but a simple thing you have to do in your day.

Thinking about the second problem, I was searching for a way to set a second condition... like... If I send a to do AND the to do begins with "get me the music" (and the name of music and artist) then Spotify searches for that name and adds the result.

I found apilio.io that would allow me to create conditions, but I'm a total noob and I couldn't manage to use Apilio.

Is there a way to get the current song for a list?

Anyone know something about it or could give me tips or references of material where I can learn and build something?